# OperationalError when converting from sqlite3 to postgresql

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried changing my db from sqlite3 to postgresql using this tutorial:

https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/optional_postgresql_installation/

but when i try to migrate i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_name
s(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "c:\Users\gudat\Documents\Arbeit\Szenario\Python\venv1\lib\site-packages\
psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbase',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

(yes i had the name changed)
Using Python 3.6.3 and psycopg2 (2.7.4).

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your postgresql server is running? Have you tried connecting to it another way (e.g. using psql or pgadmin?)

Comment: Entering `psql -U name -d dbase` ind cmd promt changes the beinning of the line to dbase=#. Guess this means its running?

Comment: Yes, it's running, but you haven't connected with the same host/port/username/password as in your `DATABASES` setting - `psql` could be connecting using a socket.

Comment: `psql -h localhost -U name -d dbase -p 5432` also works

Comment: Is it prompting you for a password when you do that?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/417) suggests that the error message can be hidden in Windows when `lc_messages` is set in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Yes i have to enter the password. Sorry I dont realy understand your comment with lc_messages.

Comment: The GitHub issue suggests there may be a bug (empty `OperationalError`) on Windows. [On this specific comment](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/417#issuecomment-277178415), the user says that changing their language from `ru-RU` to `en-US` in their `postgres.conf` helped. I don't use Windows so I can't really help any more than that.

Comment: In your link the errormessage is `psycopg2.OperationalError` but my error is `django.db.utils.OperationalError`. Still tried and changed everything to en-US, but didnt change anything

Comment: The original error in your traceback *is* `psycopg2.OperationalError`. The `django.db.utils.OperationalError` is in the later section. Note that changing `postgres.conf` didn't prevent the error, it just made the error display a useful message, e.g. `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "x"`. I'm afraid I don't have any more suggestions. Hope you get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It actually works now and I am a little ashamed of the reason: I created the username in the pgAdmin with a capital letter and expected it has to be capital in my settings.py ... small letter it is *shame*

Comment: Great, glad you figured out the problem